# Potential downsides to getting a Polish passport?

Tags: eu-citizens, polish-citizens

Due to recent "Reasons" my UK passport is not as useful as it once was for living and working in the EU. My grandfather is Polish. Which means I am able to get a Polish passport (Citizenship).

I want to do a quick check to see if there would be any downsides to this. (I will do a proper due diligence closer to the time)

I am particularly concerned if there my be National Service or Tax implications. Not just for myself but also for any children I may have. (I/They are/would be currently UK/NZ and NZ tax residents)

So my question is:

**Are there any significant downsides to getting a Polish passport, as a citizen of a different country?**

Comment: The site https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ may be better suited for this question as your question does not relate to a single travel issue.

Comment: You should ask on [expatriates.se], but [this Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_nationality_law) might get you started. Scroll down to the section on dual nationality.

Comment: Since 2010 there is no **National Service** in Poland, so from that aspect there is no problem.